# Move all members to channel command using a foor loop discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def move(ctx, channel : discord.VoiceChannel):
    for members in ctx.author.voice_channel:
        await members.move_to(channel)
```

I want the command to be used where the executor can go into a channel and use `'.move (name of channel)` and then it will move all the members in that channel to the `(name of channel)`. One of the errors I'm getting is that it's ignoring spaces, so if there's a space in the name of the voice channel, it will only include the word before the space. And also I get this:  `Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'`. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use keyword only arguments to process the rest of the message as a single argument.  You also need to access the callers voice channel through `ctx.author.voice.channel`

```
from discord.ext.commands import check

def in_voice_channel():  # check to make sure ctx.author.voice.channel exists
    def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel
    return check(predicate)

@in_voice_channel()
@bot.command()
async def move(ctx, *, channel : discord.VoiceChannel):
    for members in ctx.author.voice.channel.members:
        await members.move_to(channel)
```

Comment: 'VoiceChannel' object is not iterable
I tried your code and got this error. I've never seen this error before. ?

Comment: As the exception message says, [`VoiceChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel) itself is not iterable. You'll want to use the [`VoiceChannel.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.members) attribute instead for the members connected to that voice channel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote arguments with spaces in them for [positional parameters for commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#positional).
Alternatively, you can use a [keyword-only argument for the command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments) to consume the rest of the input.

As the exception message is telling you, [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) objects do not have a `voice_channel` attribute.
You'll want to use the [`Member.voice`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.voice) attribute instead, to get the [`VoiceState`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState) object for that user/member. Then, you can use [`VoiceState.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState.channel) for the [`VoiceChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel) that the user/member is connected to.

Also, note that you can't iterate `VoiceChannel` itself for the members connected to that voice channel. You'll want to use the [`VoiceChannel.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.members) attribute instead.